# Best way to fetch max date using jpa repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a table event

```sql
CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `otherTableId` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `updateDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  KEY `otherTableId` (`otherTableId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I am using jpa repository,
What is best way to replicate below query which can have multiple ids to query and need max date row for each id

```sql
select 
    A.otherTableId, 
    A.updateDateTime 
from 
    event as A, 
    (
      select 
          otherTableId, 
          max(updateDateTime) as updateDateTime 
      from 
          event 
      where 
          otherTableId in (5,88,77,96,10054) 
      group by 
          otherTableId) as B 
where 
    A.otherTableId = B.otherTableId 
    and A.updateDateTime=B.updateDateTime
```

Comment: your query looks quite complex, so best way would be to use your DB query as-is using @query(nativequery = true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the @Query annotation with the nativeQuery attribute set to true.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT A.other_table_id, A.update_date_time " +
           "FROM event A, " +
           "(SELECT other_table_id, MAX(update_date_time) AS update_date_time " +
           " FROM event " +
           " WHERE other_table_id IN (:ids) " +
           " GROUP BY other_table_id) B " +
           "WHERE A.other_table_id = B.other_table_id " +
           "  AND A.update_date_time = B.update_date_time", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> findMaxDateForID(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids);
```

it gets list of ids if you want to pass one by one id you can using:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT A.other_table_id, A.update_date_time " +
       "FROM event A, " +
       "(SELECT other_table_id, MAX(update_date_time) AS update_date_time " +
       " FROM event " +
       " WHERE other_table_id=:id " +
       " GROUP BY other_table_id) B " +
       "WHERE A.other_table_id = B.other_table_id " +
       "  AND A.update_date_time = B.update_date_time", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> findMaxDateForID(@Param("id") Long id);
```